# Remove Unique Characters from String Enclosed by Parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of names in this format: Last (Maiden), First .
How can I remove the maiden name so it appears as Last,First ?

```
Name_List = ['Smith (Samsonite), Jennifer', 'Johnson (Scott), Ashley', 
'Williams, Jessica']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use a regular expression to remove anything inside a pair of parenthesis:

```
import re

Name_List = ['Smith (Samsonite), Jennifer', 'Johnson (Scott), Ashley',
             'Williams, Jessica']

Name_List = list(map(lambda x: re.sub(r'\s\(.*\)', '', x), Name_List))
print(Name_List)  # prints ['Smith, Jennifer', 'Johnson, Ashley', ...]
```